# (Matlab) Need to call only a single output from a function that produces many outputs

Tags: matlab

### As stated, I would only need one of the output from a function that returns many outputs.

A quick example:

```
function [out1, out2] = myFunction (input)
out1=input+1;
out2=input+2;
end
```

---

In my other script, I need the out2 only. How should I format in such a way that it returns me out2?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
  [~, out] = myFunction(input)
```